# Blazor Server Side - Cookie Authentication - check cookie expiration date

Tags: blazor

I use Cookie Authentication in a Blazor server side application. Is there a way to check whether cookie has expired?

I've tried to get cookie expiration date with **HttpContextAccessor** but there's only an encrypted value of a cookie.

Comment: You shouldn't be using HttpContextAccessor  in Server Blazor Apps.  See this github's issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12601#issuecomment-525804729

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be checking cookie expiration on the server. A legitimate client will remove the cookie itself when it expires, and a rogue client can lie about the expiration. If you want to expire a login token or something, you need to handle it completely separately from the expiration of the cookie itself for it to be secure.

Comment: I thought Auth cookies, made by .net core framework, are encrypted and prone to tampering

Comment: You can only encrypt the content of cookies, not metadata like the expiration dates.